# How to put the button on the top of the image?

Tags: html, css, z-index

I am trying to put a button on a picture. I have tried doing z-index and all but it does not seem to work.

```
 <div class="landing-img">
      <img src="CartoonPalace.png" class="img-fluid" style="position:relative; z-index: -1;"  alt="">
      <a href="" class="btn btn-outline-primary" style="position: absolute; z-index: 1000;">Start Exploring</a>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the position of your absolute positioned element, for example, you could specify `left: 0px`. Note that I have changed the image url in order to make a functional demo, you should change it in your own code.

```html
 <div class="landing-img" style="position:relative;">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" class="img-fluid" alt="">
      <a href="" class="btn btn-outline-primary" style="position: absolute; left: 0px;">Start Exploring</a>
  </div>
```

Comment: this doesn't help bro, i still don't see the button.

Comment: I have updated my answer in order to run the demo. I see the button there

Comment: can you also tell me how i am supposed to place the button at a certain location, i tried using positioning by specifying the left and top values, but when the page is resized, it pushes the button below the image.

Comment: @Flamiooo The parent of the button (the element that wraps it) should have `position: relative` defined. I have updated my answer. If this still does not make it work, you should create a new demo for me to look at, otherwise I'm unable to debug

Comment: @Flamiooo Glad it worked out! Could you, then, accept this answer? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="" class="btn btn-outline-primary" style="position: absolutee; left: 10px; bottom: 10px; z-index: 2;">Start Exploringg</a>
```

Comment: Code dumps do not make for good answers. You should explain *how* and *why* this solves their problem. I recommend reading, "[How do I write a good answer?"](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). This can help future users learn and eventually apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback/upvotes from users, when the code is explained.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this very easily by setting the image as the background of the parent div and then centering the button.

```
  <div class="landing-img">
      <a href="" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Start Exploring</a>
  </div>

    // css
    .landing-img{
        background-image: url(CartoonPalace.png)
        display:flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
    }
```

Comment: but the problem is i am going to be using django to render these templates, and it requires the specification of the static files.